# Alternative Free Static Maps API embed using IMG tag

Tags: html, maps

i'm looking for alternative free static maps API that support HTTPS by simply embed using `<img src="URL MAPS" />`. Because Google Maps static API is not FREE anymore and must be activated with billing information. Is there anyone knows, what should i use?

Comment: You should check again. Google Maps static API is FREE with request limited

Comment: Could you please give me example? I already try using img tag and always get broken link image. And also i already using API key and check in browser console, and get error "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started" which is need credit card. I don't want to do that.